# JSON Serialization Issue with Bidirectional OneToOne Relationship

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I have two Java entities with a bi-directional One To One relationship between them: `Sinistre` and `RapportTechnique`. When I generate the JSON file to send to the front end, I encounter unwanted recursion.

Class **Sinistre**

```
@Data   
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = "sinistre")
public class Sinistre extends Audit {

    @Column
    private String code;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime dateIncident;

    @Column
    private double montantIndem;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "structure_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Structure structure;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sinistre")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private RapportTechnique rapportTechnique;
}
```

Classe **RapportTechnique**

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@Table(name = "rapportTech")
public class RapportTechnique extends Audit {
    @Column
    private String reference;

    @Column
    private String nature_Sinistre;

    @Column
    private String causes_Sinistre;

    @Column
    private String date_intervention;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sinistre_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Sinistre sinistre;
}
```

I tried the `@JsonIgnore` annotation, but it completely ignores the relationship in the JSON. I discovered the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations, which solve the recursion but only in one direction. How can I maintain the bidirectional relationship while avoiding recursion when generating the JSON file for the 'Sinistre' entity, which contains a reference to 'RapportTechnique' and vice versa?

Comment: Have you seen Jackson tutorials on the subject? https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion suggests @JsonIdentityInfo is pretty close to what you want, putting in the Id values instead of the full entity when it finds it is already been serialized once

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonIgnoreProperties:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "sinistre")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("sinistre")
private RapportTechnique rapportTechnique;
```

and

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sinistre_id")
@JsonIgnoreProperties("rapportTechnique")
private Sinistre sinistre;
```

Answer (score 0):

Choose one class as the principal and in the secondary class, fetch the object lazily using the **@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)** annotation. This ensures that the associated object is loaded lazily, improving performance by fetching it only when needed.